# How to resolve PHP error log in cpanel server causing blank screen php page

Tags: php

Good day to everyone. I found this below php coding errors in the "error_log" which is in my cpanel server root directory, causing the php page for a schoolsystem I developed to be blank screen on browsers. I have tried, all I could but not working for me.

```
**`BELOW IS THE ERROR_LOG CONTENT:`**

[03-Dec-2016 10:17:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php(4): include()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 10:19:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php:14
Stack trace:
#0 /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php(4): include()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 10:19:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php:14
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: style in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 17
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 18
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 19
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: save in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 20
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stype in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 21
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: import in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 23
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 24
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 25
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 26
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 27
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 262
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 262
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 278
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 278
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 288
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 288
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 298
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 298
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 308
[03-Dec-2016 10:21:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 308
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:52 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:52 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: style in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 17
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:52 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 18
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:52 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 19
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:52 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: save in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 20
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:52 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stype in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 21
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:52 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 47
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: style in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 17
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 18
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 19
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: save in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 20
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stype in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 21
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: import in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 23
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 24
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 25
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 26
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 27
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: aval in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 136
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ain in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 163
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 173
[03-Dec-2016 10:22:53 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: aval in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 188
[03-Dec-2016 10:24:02 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 10:24:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: import in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 23
[03-Dec-2016 10:24:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 24
[03-Dec-2016 10:24:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 25
[03-Dec-2016 10:24:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 26
[03-Dec-2016 10:24:02 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 27
[03-Dec-2016 10:24:05 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: import in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 23
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 24
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 25
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 26
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 27
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 262
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 262
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 278
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 278
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 288
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 288
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 298
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 298
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 308
[03-Dec-2016 11:21:39 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 308
[03-Dec-2016 11:26:58 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:07 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: style in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 17
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 18
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 19
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: save in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 20
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stype in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 21
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: import in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 23
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 24
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 25
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 26
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 27
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 262
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 262
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 278
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 278
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 288
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 288
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 298
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 298
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 308
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:09 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 308
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:40 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:40 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: style in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 17
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:40 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 18
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:40 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 19
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:40 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: save in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 20
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:40 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stype in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 21
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:40 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 47
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: style in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 17
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 18
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 19
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: save in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 20
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stype in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 21
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: import in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 23
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 24
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 25
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 26
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 27
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: aval in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 136
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 136
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ain in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 136
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 136
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ain in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 136
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 136
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ain in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 163
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 163
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: aval in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 173
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 173
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: aval in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 188
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:41 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 188
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:59 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: import in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 23
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 24
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 25
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 26
[03-Dec-2016 11:27:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 27
[03-Dec-2016 11:28:00 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/functions/connection.php on line 14
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: style in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 17
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: url in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 18
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 19
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: save in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 20
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: stype in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 21
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: import in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 23
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 24
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 25
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: host in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 26
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: database in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 27
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 262
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 262
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 278
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 278
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 288
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 288
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 298
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 298
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: val in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 308
[03-Dec-2016 21:09:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/xayoutys/public_html/schoolsystem/setup.php on line 308
```

**CONNECTION.PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$aut_host = 'localhost';//e.g localhost
$aut_user = 'xayoutys_sman';
$aut_pass = 'school009#';
$aut_db = 'xayoutys_sman';

//$connect = mysql_pconnect('localhost', 'root', '');
//mysql_select_db('xsman');

/*$connect = mysql_pconnect('127.0.0.1', 'kokotrad_sman', 'cool');
$xtzone = mysql_query("SET time_zone = 'Africa/Lagos'");
mysql_select_db('kokotrad_sman');*/

$connect = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'xayoutys_sman', 'school009#');
$xtzone = mysql_query("SET time_zone = 'Africa/Lagos'");
mysql_select_db('xayoutys_sman');

if(@$page != 'setup')
{
//school type
$qtype = mysql_query("select type from type where id = 1");
$qtype_row = mysql_fetch_row($qtype);
$type = $qtype_row[0];

//sms sender id
$xsendq = mysql_query("select sender from smsapi where id = 1");
if(mysql_num_rows($xsendq) > 0)
{
    $xsendq_row = mysql_fetch_row($xsendq);
    $xsender = $xsendq_row[0];
}

//get style
$cstyle = mysql_query("select style, school_name, url, logo_ext from info where id = 1");
$cstyle_row = mysql_fetch_row($cstyle);
$xcstyle = $cstyle_row[0];
$csch_name = $cstyle_row[1];
$curlx = $cstyle_row[2];
$clogo_ext = $cstyle_row[3];

if($type == 'university')
{
    $tl = 'Lecturer';
    $cac = 'Association';
    $cco = 'Course';
}
elseif($type == 'school')
{
    $tl = 'Teacher';
    $cac = 'Club';
    $cco = 'Subject';
}

}//setup
?>
```

**SETUP.PHP CODES**

```
<?php
$page = 'setup';

include('functions/connection.php');
include('functions/error_success.php');
include('objects/query.php');
include('objects/upload_download.php');

//check stat
$check = new select();
$check->pick('info', 'stat', 'id', "1", '', 'record', '', '', '=', '');
if($check->count > 0)
{
    $check_row = mysql_fetch_row($check->query);
}

$style = $_POST['style'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$save = $_POST['save'];
$stype = $_POST['stype'];

$import = $_POST['import'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$host = $_POST['host'];
$database = $_POST['database'];

if($import)
{
    $val = new validate();
    $val->valid("$database,$username,$host");
    if($val->error_code < 1)
    {
        // Name of the file
$filename = 'sman.sql';
// MySQL host
$mysql_host = $host;
// MySQL username
$mysql_username = $username;
// MySQL password
$mysql_password = $password;
// Database name
$mysql_database = $database;

// Connect to MySQL server
mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Error connecting to MySQL server: ' . mysql_error());
// Select database
mysql_select_db($mysql_database) or die('Error selecting MySQL database: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: `mysql_select_db` wont work with `mysqli` (in connection.php). Check that your `POST` indexes exist before trying to use them. Why are you making a a second DB connection in setup.php?

Comment: You are mixing two different database connection drivers, that won't work. `mysql_...()` and `mysqli_...()` have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Most likely you are using php7 which does not include the old, long deprecated and outdated `mysql` connector. Use the newer `mysqli` connector instead.

Comment: The blank screen would be caused by `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()`. That function is commented out in all of the code you are showing though..